# How to connect result with http request in pipeline distributed architecture?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mapreduce, zeromq, reduce

I want to build following architecture:

ventilator in my case - rest application and this application distribute work on several workers:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> processSockets(@RequestBody String inputJson)
    socketService.sendToSocket(inputJson);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("ololo", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

But at this case server send response to client right after send task to queue. But I want to response with result which I got from worker.

I got result from worker in another thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true)
            System.out.println(new String(sinkSocket.recv(0)));
    }
}).start();
```

[image]

How to bind this thread with response to rest client service ?

Comment: What version of Spring MVC and Servlet API?

Comment: @colini Most fresh